# Pseudo proof of harmonic serie convergence? where did I mistep?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We know that $|1/n|$ goes to $0$ so:

$|1/n|<\epsilon$, for all $\epsilon<<1$ and $n \geq n_0$ (its definition of converge was stated by my professor)

so:

$|1/n|<\epsilon^n$
, since  $\epsilon^n<<1$

then:

$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|1/n|<\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\epsilon^n, n\geq n_0$

as $\epsilon<<1$ so $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\epsilon^n$ converges then the harmonic serie does too for all $n \geq n_0$ since backward $n_0$ we have finite terms so the harmonic serie converges in $\mathbb{N}$. Where did I mistep? I really couldn't figure this out.

Comment: It’s just not true that $1/n< \epsilon^n$ (and I don’t understand your argument to the contrary). In fact, for any $\epsilon\in (0,1)$ there is an $N$ such that $1/n>\epsilon^n$ for all $n>N$.

Comment: if it holds for any number $<<1$ so it holds to $\epsilon^n<<1$

Comment: $1/n$ is eventually less than any fixed positive number, but $\epsilon^n$ isn’t a fixed number, it’s a function of $n$. It’s a sequence that converges to $0$, and happens to converge to zero much more rapidly than $1/n$.

Comment: could you put this out more clear? Why can't I just function it?

Comment: Why could you? The definition of $1/n$ converging to zero is that for any $\epsilon 
>0$ there is an $N$ such that $|1/n|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. It doesn't say that for any sequence $a_n$ where is an $N$ such that $|1/n|<a_n$ for all $n>N.$ That's badly false... consider the sequence $a_n=1/(n+1),$ for instance.... we always have $1/n>1/(n+1).$

Comment: The real issue with your logic is that $1/n<\epsilon$ does not imply $1/n<\epsilon^n$. For example, $1/3<0.5$ is true but that does not imply $1/3<0.5^3$. Based on your reply to spaceisdarkgreen, I suspect you don't understand $n_0$ depends on what $\epsilon$ is; you think you can just replace $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon^n$ since they're both $<1$ and then "$1/n<\epsilon$ for $n\ge n_0$" turns into "$1/n<\epsilon^n$ for $n\ge n_0$"znd remains true. You can't do that because $n_0$ depends on which value $<1$ is chosen.

Comment: “function it”? ‘Function” isn’t a verb”; whatever is ‘it’?

Comment: @runway44 yes, usually for every means for all, so instead of using for every $\epsilon$ there is a $n_0$ I used, for all $\epsilon$ there is a $n_0$

Comment: Either your professor  mis-stated the definition of convergence to $0$ or you oversimplified it when you quoted it. It should say that, for every $\epsilon>0$ **there exists** $n_0$ such that, for every $n\ge n_0$, $|1/n|<\epsilon$. Not only the presence of "there exists $n_0$" but also its position in the sentence are important, and I fear that omitting this phrase is the root of your error.

Comment: @AndreasBlass it's

Comment: it's what? ${}{}$

Comment: @runway44 I suspect that Davi America meant that "its" in my comment should be "it's", but in fact "its" is correct and "it's" would be wrong.

Comment: @AndreasBlass your answer is right